# Refrescar búsqueda en Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
 url(r'^consultar_laboratorio/$',consultar_laboratorio,name='consultar_laboratorio'),
```

---

Mi view:

```
def consultar_laboratorio(request):
import pdb
ordenes_list = None
ordenes = None
qr = False
er = False
qd = False
tp = False
oe = False
ref = None
try: 
    form = BuscarFormLB()
    #realizado_por = request.user
    #dispensario = Perfil.obtener_dispensario(realizado_por)
    ordenes = OrdenLaboratorio.objects.all().order_by('-cita__fecha_ingreso')
            ####
    if request.method == 'GET':
                try:
                    ref = request.GET.get('t', None);
                except:
                    pass
                if 'q' in request.GET:
                    if request.GET['q'] != '':
                        qr = True
                        q = request.GET['q'].split()
                        for param in q:
                                ordenes = ordenes.filter(
                                        Q(cita__paciente__apellidos__icontains=param) | Q(cita__paciente__numero_identificacion__icontains=param) | Q(cita__paciente__nombres__icontains=param) | Q(cita__id__icontains=param) | Q(cita__fecha_ingreso__icontains=param)
                                        )
                if ref != None:
                    qr = True
                    param = ref
                        #q = request.GET['q'].split()
                    ordenes = ordenes.filter(
                                        Q(cita__paciente__apellidos__icontains=param) | Q(cita__paciente__numero_identificacion__icontains=param) | Q(cita__paciente__nombres__icontains=param) | Q(cita__id__icontains=param) | Q(cita__fecha_ingreso__icontains=param)
                                        )


                if 'tipos_orden' in request.GET:                     
                    if request.GET['tipos_orden'] != '-' and request.GET['tipos_orden'] != '':
                        tp = True
                        ordenes = ordenes.filter(tipo=request.GET['tipos_orden'])

                if 'estados' in request.GET: 
                    if request.GET['estados'] != '-' and request.GET['estados'] != '':
                        er = True
                        ordenes = ordenes.filter(estado=request.GET['estados'])

                if 'orden_enterprise' in request.GET: 
                    #if request.GET['orden_enterprise'] ==  True:
                    oe = True
                    ordenes = ordenes.exclude(orden_enterprise__isnull=False)
                        #ordenes = ordenes.filter(orden_enterprise__isnull=False)

                if 'fecha_desde' in request.GET:
                    if request.GET['fecha_desde'] != '':
                        qd = True
                        desde = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET['fecha_desde'], '%d/%m/%Y')
                        ordenes = ordenes.filter(fecha_creacion__gte=desde)

                if 'fecha_hasta' in request.GET:
                    if request.GET['fecha_hasta'] != '':
                        qd = True
                        hasta = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET['fecha_hasta'], '%d/%m/%Y')
                        ordenes = ordenes.filter(fecha_creacion__lte=hasta)

                if not qr and not er and not qd and not oe and not tp:

                    if not Perfil.es_admin(request.user) and not Perfil.es_admin_dispensario(request.user):
                        today_min = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min)
                        today_max = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.max)
                        ordenes = ordenes.filter(fecha_creacion__range=(today_min, today_max))

                if not Perfil.es_admin(request.user) and not Perfil.es_admin_dispensario(request.user):
                    if Perfil.es_agendaimagen(request.user):
                        imagenes = imagenes.filter(estado__in=(ImagenesCitaSolicitud.IMAGEN_CREADA,ImagenesCitaSolicitud.IMAGEN_PROGRAMADO)).order_by('-fecha_creacion')
                    if Perfil.es_radioauxiliar(request.user) or Perfil.es_radiologo(request.user):
                        imagenes = imagenes.exclude(estado=ImagenesCitaSolicitud.IMAGEN_CREADA).order_by('-fecha_programada')

    paginator = Paginator(ordenes, 25)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        ordenes_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        ordenes_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        ordenes_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
except ApplicationError,e:
    request.session['error_msg'] = e.__str__()


   return render(request,'citas/templates/consultar_laboratorio.html',{"page_title":u"Consultar Laboratorio","imagenes":ordenes_list,"form":form})
```

Cuando realizo una búsqueda me filtra y me retorna la búsqueda,

---

En mi HTML  tengo esto

```
 <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="MM_openBrWindow('laboratorioinforme/{{img.id}}','CargarInforme','scrollbars=yes,width=1024,height=768')">

                {% if img.estado = 'C'%}
                    Ord.Enterprise
                {% endif %}

                {% if img.estado = 'E'%}
                    Informe
                {% endif %}
                {% if img.estado = 'D'%}
                    Documentos
                {% endif %}
                {% if img.estado = 'R'%}
                    Vincular
                {% endif %}
                {% if img.estado = 'P'%}
                    Finalizado
                {% endif %}
            </button></td>
```

Que es un botón en cada fila que dependiendo del estado se abre una pantalla emergente para llenar unos campos. Una vez lleno le doy guardar y se cierra automáticamente la pantalla emergente.

Lo que deseo es que en mi pantalla principal se refresque el cambio o el dato llenado en la pantalla emergente y si es posible, se filtre solo por el elemento que realice la última búsqueda.